# How to proceed from login screen to the next screen? JPanel, JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I have a question regarding building GUI applications. I feel like the title of this question is not really accurate but I could not think of a better one.

What is the proper way of building the application? Should I just create one JFrame, then change the panels in that JFrame as needed? Or should I always create new JFrame and get rid of the old one when moving from one thing to another?

For example, I have the JFrame containing a JPanel that has few text fields and JLabels. User enters username and password, clicks a login button to continue. Should a completely new JFrame appear, or should a new JPanel be created instead, using the old JFrame?

Comment: Have a look at the CardLayout.

Comment: CardLayout seems good. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Extra thanks to HFOE for an awesome post on how to use cardlayout!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends, but often it's better if you can reuse the same window. Often, you might want to use a JDialog / JOptionPane to handle login. Dialog windows are meant to be more disposable

Answer (score 4):

Another way is use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), if autentification passed, then to display [JMenuBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) with `JMenuItems` for access to another cards,

Answer (score 1):

My recomendation is to use 1 JFrame with a JDesktopPane as the "base" of your aplication.

You can then pop any dialogs or internal frames from the JDesktopPane. This works even if you do not use internal frames.

So, in answer to your question, I would first build 1 JFrame with a JMenubar, JToolbar and JDesktopPane. Then, on top of all that, I would open a JDialog with the logging fields and a nice splash screen. If it logs ok, you then close the dialog and enable the Menu bar and tool bar. From there you keep openning and closing any dialogs or internal frames...

Hope this helps ...